# How keep services alive when the device turned off?

Tags: android, service, clock

There is a way to keep the **service** running even if the device turned **off**!??
(like a **Alarm** Clock still working even the device off or no battery or the clock setting still).
I was looking for some information on this question and could not find even a hint. If someone could answer me this it would really help me and I would be grateful

Comment: No, you cannot do anything. Nothing is running (at least at the application level) when the device is off.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't.  Instead you restart the service at boot time, by registering a BOOT_COMPLETE broadcast receiver in your manifest.